# Could not get response using volley lib

Tags: android, android-volley

I got stuck with Volley library, any one please help me out.
The question is, I'm using Volley library for API call, it works when I call in a traditional method. I tried to use Volley library for better response but I'm not getting any response, some times I get the response but many times it fails. My snippet is:

```
JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                parseJSON(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter = new VolleySearchResultAdapter(searchResults, mImageLoader);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i(TAG,error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(jr);
```

And how do I do pagination using this library?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Request timeout? Where is your `RequestQueue` and where do you initialize it? also you should probably put the adapter section into the 'try' clause as to prevent exceptions and unknown behavior.

Comment: Hi Itai Hanski,
I found the problem is because of API. Api is fixed and it works fine now. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Sathish,What was the exact problem because i am also facing the same issue.Thanks in advance..